# Storage partition has become 'Bitlocker' type

Tags: partitioning, mount, encryption, windows-10, 22.04

I was running a windows 10 system with a storage partition. I used disk manager to shrink my C: drive and create a new D: partition for storage. I left all the windows stuff on C: and used D: for all my user files (Photos, Documents, Desktop, Downloads, ect.)
I eventually became frustrated with windows 10 and decided to change to Ubuntu 22.04 completely. In the past I have installed ubuntu from USB with the standard 'wipe everything and let ubuntu install how it wants' method. This time, since I had a storage partition I decided to try to learn some thing by using gparted to wipe everything that wasn't my storage partition and then install ubuntu in the newly free'd up space. I had to do a 'custom' install which you can see from the screen-grab of [gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUVVW.png).

The problem is for some reason the storage partition has become a 'Bitlocker' filesystem despite me never setting up bitlocker for anything and I can no longer mount this drive. I have tried dislocker but I don't think that is the answer since as I said I never encrypted this partition to begin with.

Comment: I have recently encountered Bitlocker too, and I think the best idea for you is to 1. backup your bitlocked partition to a separate (external) drive; 2. Reinstall Windows (if possible from a backup); 3. Use Windows to unlock the bitlocked partition with a Windows tool. There are instructions via Microsoft's web-site how to unlock Bitlocker partitions. It worked for me but was a bit difficult to find relevant information. However, this is not about Ubuntu, I think you find better help at some Windows forum.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try that and report back :)
Do you know why the partition would become a bitlocker partition?

Answer (score 0):

- I think the manufacturer can set Windows to use BitLocker.
- If Windows is using Bitlocker, it can be cumbersome if you shrink your Windows and/or data partition(s) and install Ubuntu alongside Windows.

  It is best to prepare by turning off BitLocker before those operations. You can find a page about BitLocker, if you search for it in the search window of 'Settings' in Windows. After Ubuntu is installed (and you have a good backup of your systems) you can turn on BitLocker again if you wish, but then Ubuntu will not see the files in that partition.
- Otherwise, if it is 'too late' to use Windows, you can find the relevant information and key to unlock Bitlocker via the internet. I am not sure if it is necessary, but I used my account at Microsoft in order to verify, that I am the owner of that particular bitlocked partition.

Comment: Great, thank you for your response. I didn't realize windows used Bitlocker by default. I had already removed Windows to free up space for Ubuntu so I think in my case it is 'too late'. I suppose I can try to find the relevant info and key to unlock it, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, that was what I had to do, and it ***is*** possible. Good luck :-)